# Connect to VPN when requesting Mapped Drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, vpn

Is it possible for windows (7 and XP) to automatically connect to a VPN when a certain Drive is needed. So when you double click in My Computer (Computer in 7) on say the J Drive, which is mapped to a remote Server it automatically connects then loads the Drive.

Comment: How do you regurlarly connect to the VPN? (VPN client with RSA, VPN with domain credentials).

Comment: Not possible unless a full custom app were made to do this special task. Instead, a script could be made to connect to VPN first.

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically, but you can write a script that would check for the VPN, run it if it's not connected, then map the drive and open it.

Search how to use `rasdial` for connecting with the Windows VPN client. Then, you can use the `NET USE x: \\server\sharename` command to connect a drive letter, then `start x:` to open it in Windows Explorer